# Sound change charts/lists

Tags: phonology, sound-change, grimms-law

I am looking for a summary of sound change laws of various language families. For example for Indo-European, Uralic, N. Caucasian, Semitic but also within Indo-European e.g. Germanic, Greek etc. Is there a source summarizing this or do I need to make a research separately for each one of those. In any of the cases, please suggest me some bibiography to have a look at.

Thanks in advance!

Appart from the accepted answer, let me add the following chart for Indo-European: http://www.palaeolexicon.com/Content/PiePhonology.aspx

Comment: I-E is in one book, anyway: N.E. Collinge. 1985. _The Laws of Indo-European._ John Benjamins, Amsterdam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kümmel, Martin: Konsonantenwandel, Bausteine zu einer Typologie des Lautwandels und ihre Konsequenzen für die vergleichende Rekonstruktion. Wiesbaden: Reichert 2007. LVI + 482 S. ISBN 987-3-89500-590-9.

Answer (score 1):

There is a compendium of historical correspondences [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17784007/Index.pdf). It is a convenience sample based on whatever sources the (anonymous) author finds, so for example for Bantu it relies on Harry Johnston's, errm, pioneering work. There isn't any linguistic unit "Proto-British East African", there are gaps (there was no *h* in Bantu so what does the change "*h→Ø/V_V*" apply to?). It is surprisingly weak on Uralic (given the volume of research available on Uralic), but it is a work in progress, and worth consulting.